# unable to render lists of data while using class based component in both parent and child in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, function, class

I am trying to get the lists of data from parent component to child component to display it but unable to do it

when i tried to console.log the sub it is showing the data but unable to return the div and render it into the screen

```
import React from 'react';

class RenderSub extends React.Component {


    renderedLists = () => {

        this.props.lists.subjects[this.props.lists.sem].map(sub => {
            console.log(sub);
            return (
                <div key={Math.random()}>
                    {sub}
                </div>
            );
        });
    } 

    render() {

        if(this.props.lists.sem === "") {
            return <div></div>;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderedLists()}

            </div>
        );
    }

}   

export default RenderSub;
```

Design and Analysis of Algorithm

Computer Architecture & Organisation

Database Management System

Microprocessor & Microcontroller Based Systems

Probability and Statistics

RDBMS Lab

Microprocessor & Microcontroller Lab

Programming in Java

Comment: It seems like you forgot to actually return the computed array in `renderedLists()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to return array in `renderedLists`

```
renderedLists = () => {
    return this.props.lists.subjects[this.props.lists.sem].map(sub => {
        console.log(sub);
        return (
            <div key={Math.random()}>
                {sub}
            </div>
        );
    });
} 

render() {
    if(this.props.lists.sem === "") {
        return <div></div>;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderedLists()}
        </div>
    );
}
```